# Using Collection on Dependency Property and Intellisense

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

What I`m trying to achieve is to use a DP and in XAML to have access with Intellisense to the members of that DP the same way like you can do it with an enum. I cannot use enum in my case because i need to build the list that the DP will return dynamically.

Here is my approach, but no success:

```cs
public List<string> OutputValue
  {
     get { return (List<string>)GetValue(OutputValueProperty ); }
     set { SetValue(OutputValueProperty , value); }
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty OutputValueProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("OutputValue", typeof(List<string>), typeof(MyControlType), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("m", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None, OnPropChanged, CoerceOutputValue));

  private static object CoerceOutputValue(DependencyObject d, object basevalue)
  {
     return _list; // this is a list that i build dynamically and i returned it here
  }

  #endregion


  private static void OnPropChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.Property.Name.Equals("OutputValue"))
     {
        d.CoerceValue(CoerceOutputValue);
     }
  }
```

Any ideas how can I resolve this issue?

Regards.

Comment: Usually IntelliSens don't autocomplete more than the Control property names. It'won't autocomplete sub members. And anyway if you build your collection at runtime intellisens can not know them as it performs before your code is really executed. But your question is not really clear.

Comment: I think you understood correctly my question even I didn't formulate it so good. Another idea that might work, I`m not sure yet, if I build few Enums will i be able to switch between them on run time based on some external input?